# flatMap strange behaviour on List of List of Integers

Tags: scala, flatmap

In Scala:

```
scala> val xs = List(List(1, 3, 5), List(3, 4, 30))
xs: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 3, 5), List(3, 4, 30))

scala> xs flatMap {x => x + 1}
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: String
              xs flatMap {x => x + 1}
```

Why?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to flat your list before executing map:

```
xs.flatten.map { _ + 1 }
```

The reason for your error is that flatMap doesn't flatten the collection on which you execute it, it flattens the results returning by the function in its argument.

Answer (score 2):

`String` in that error message is an unfortunately misleading inference.

The error the compiler ideally would have given you is

```
found   : Int => Int
required: Int => List[Int]
```

Comment: I accept your answer because this was what I am asking about

Answer (score 1):

`x` in the `flatMap` is a `List[Int]` not an `Int`, two solutions come to mind:

```
scala> xs.flatMap(identity).map(_ + 1)
res2: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 6, 4, 5, 31)

scala> xs.flatMap(_.map(_ + 1))
res3: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 6, 4, 5, 31)
```

Comment: You can use `flatten` instead of `flatMap(identity)`. A for expression is also a good fit here.